# Christmas Market, Baden Baden, Germany

Tags: germany, hotels, buses

I'm flying to Baden Baden soon and I hope I'll manage to go to the Christmas Market, I've never been there. I'm trying to find an hotel by the market so when I wake up I can hang around. According to [this website](https://www.europeanbestdestinations.com/christmas-markets/baden-baden/) it seems to be near the Lichtentaler Allee, I can see there are few hotels by this place. Is the town center accessible from there maybe using a bus? If someone has been there can you tell me if the market is big, so it would actually make sense to book a room by the market, or maybe stay more toward the center and to the other way around for the bus.

Thank you

Comment: Baden Baden is not sooo big. If you know where the Christmas market is located you can find a nearby hotel and walk. The market opens at 11 in the morning what means it depends on the time you get up, whether you can hang around in the morning.  https://visit.baden-baden.de/en/events/baden-baden-christmas-market

Comment: Please don’t overestimate the touristic appeal of the Christmas market of a midsize German city, especially when traveling alone.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: A German Christmas market mostly consists of booths selling quirky gifts(candles, carved wood, Christmas decorations, jewelry, etc.) and food stands. If you aren't interested in those shops the main activity is eating and drinking. While the ambiance, shops, food, and Glühwein ("glow wine" - hot spiced wine) are enjoyable it is more of an evening activity the same as grabbing some cocktails with friends rather than a full day worth of activities. 
I recommend you to go there in the evening (for a nice ambiance), bring some appetite and especially warm clothes.

Comment: You were right, the market is small but it's definetly worth going, your suggestion was good. I think next time I'll go I'll try to explore the Schawrtzwald.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Christmas market is right in the center of the city at the Kurhaus (Collonades).  https://visit.baden-baden.de/en/events/baden-baden-christmas-market . There are plenty of hotels within easy walking distance.

As the comment mentioned, the main action starts late afternoon/early evening when it's getting dark, since the illuminations are a lot more fun and most people are done with work (on non-weekends). While it officially opens at 11am, it will be pretty quiet that early especially on weekdays.